# Deserializing objects with different representations

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I want to deserialize a JSON document that contains objects of the same type User represented in two different ways, as a full object representation or as a reference to an existing user object by name:

```
[
    {
        "User": "SomeUser"
    },
    {
        "User": {
            "Login": "SomeOtherUser",
            "Active": true
        }
    }
]
```

It's easy to write a converter that handles user objects referenced by name:

```
class User
{
    public string Id;
    public string Login;
    public bool Active;
}
    
class Document
{
    public User User;
}

class UserConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public UserConverter(Dictionary<string, User> users)
    {
        _users = users;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var res = typeof(User).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        return res;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var name = ((User)value)?.Login;
        writer.WriteValue(name);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var name = reader.Value?.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            return null;
        _users.TryGetValue(name, out var res);
        return res;
    }

    readonly Dictionary<string, User> _users;
}
// ....
    static void Test2()
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
            Converters =
            {
                new UserConverter(new Dictionary<string, User> { { "SomeUser", new User() }})
            }
        };
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Document>>("[{\"User\": \"SomeUser\"}, {\"User\": {\"Login\": \"SomeUser\",\"Active\": true}}]", settings);
    }
```

However, this results in deserialization errors when full User objects are encountered: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not find member 'Login' on object of type 'Document'. Path '[1].User.Login'"
Any ideas how to make it support both?

Comment: I don't understand why you're caching users in a dictionary. It isn't relevant to the question and is not threadsafe as implemented.

Comment: Are you certain that the reference will always appear **after** the full object representation in the file?  Also, what does `User` look like?  Does it have a public parameterless constructor?

Comment: What is the error that appears?

Comment: Also, when **serializing**, your current converter will always write the user name and never write the full object representation.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @X39 see the update

Comment: @dbc I know, but this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't actually care about the *contents* of the "full object representation" representation for `User`, right?  All you need to do is pick out the Login string and look it up in the dictionary?  Or do you also need to **populate** the users dictionary when a user isn't found?

Comment: @dbc I do care, and when the user is not present in the dictionary the converter should create a new object. However, this is out of scope of *this* question.